# react js google translate not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-translate

In React JS tried to implement google translate, and included translate component in my script file.

**Googletranslate.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GoogleTranslate extends Component {
    googleTranslateElementInit () {
        //alert("test2")
        /* eslint-disable no-new */
        new window.google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'pt', layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element')
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        // alert("test")

        var addScript = document.createElement('script');
        addScript.setAttribute('src', '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit');        
        document.body.appendChild(addScript);  
        window.googleTranslateElementInit = this.googleTranslateElementInit;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // <script type='text/javascript' src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit' />
            <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
          );
     }
}

export default GoogleTranslate;
```

**Adminlogin.js**:

```
import GoogleTranslate from '../Applicant/GoogleTranslate';
```

I'm using this component included in Adminlogin.js file by using `<GoogleTranslate />`.

And included the component in my files, when I login to the site and after logout, when I navigate to homepage, there are two language bars.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLupf.png]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in fuctional component works fine

```
 const SamplePage = () => {

 const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
   new window.google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT }, 'google_translate_element')
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    var addScript = document.createElement('script');
    addScript.setAttribute('src', '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit');
    document.body.appendChild(addScript);
    window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="title gx-mb-4"><IntlMessages id="sidebar.samplePage"/></h2>
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
      <div className="gx-d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h4>Start building your app. Happy Coding!</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default SamplePage
```

Answer (score 2):

The duplication or multiplication of the language bars is as a result of `document.body.appendChild(addScript)` being called every time the page loads/renders.

To resolve this, add the plugin initialisation to your `public > index.html` file as follows:

```
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" async></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {
          pageLanguage: "en",
          layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL,
        }, 
        'google_translate_element'
      );
    }
  </script>
```

Then, change your `GoogleTranslate` component to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GoogleTranslate extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
          );
     }
}

export default GoogleTranslate;
```

If this works for you, kindly up vote. If it didn't, don't hesitate to drop a comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For Next JS

```
<Script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" onLoad={() => {
        const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
            new window.google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en'} , 'google_translate_element')
        }
        window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
}}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made

Answer (score 0):

Because in this.googleTranslateElementInit context can't find correct this.

You can in constructor bind function：

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.googleTranslateElementInit = this.googleTranslateElementInit.bind(this);
}
```

or
use arrow function bind in class

```
googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function BlackNavBar() {
  const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
    new window.google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: window.google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element')
   }
   
   useEffect(() => {
     var addScript = document.createElement('script');
     addScript.setAttribute('src', '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit');
     document.body.appendChild(addScript);
     window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
   }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <header id="header" className="black-header">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div className="logo">
              <a href="/" aria-label="Hub">
                <GoDaddyLogoBlack />
              </a>
            </div>
            <button
              className="navbar-toggler collapsed"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#headerMenu"
              aria-controls="headerMenu"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span className="menu-lines"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="header-menu">
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="headerMenu">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">                
                <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
                </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
}

export default BlackNavBar;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

saikrishna chowdhary solution worked for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31338108)