# NextJS: Reloading Ads Javascript and Ad Slots on Route Change

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a custom javascript for running ads on my NextJS site. This is provided by the ad provider / ad exchange.

It looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.adsite.com/static/js/ad.js" ></script>
```

Along with this I have div tags that I place on the web page, for example:

```
<div id="ad-tag-6098" ></div>
<div id="ad-tag-6099" ></div>
<div id="ad-tag-6076" ></div>
```

These three div tags are three ad slots on a page and get populated with the ad using the ad.js javascript.

This works fine on a normal load /reload of a page.

However, when I navigate to a page using the internal navigation router, this javascript doesn't get triggered and the ad doesn't display.

What is the correct way to reload the ad.js so that the div tags (ad slots) display the ad correctly, and also refresh correctly even when we navigate through the nextjs router? Can you please help?

UPDATE: This problem is even deeper than I thought. Just reloading of javascript is not enough. Since these are ad slots, when the page transitions / route changes, the used ad slots stay in the memory, so the ad script treats them as already displayed. This causes an error.

The desired behaviour is as follows:

1. when the ad component is rendered, it defines the ad slot and displays it,
2. when route is changed, all defined slots are removed from the memory,
3. after going to a different page, ad components on that page define new slots and display them.

Comment: Once the script is loaded there should really be no need to hit the script again, does it have no API you can reasonably discern and use to interact with it as the router does its thing?

Comment: I checked with the ad provider about this, but unfortunately, the javascript must execute again in order for the ad to load.

Comment: @asanas please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might know but I wanted to remind you that there are listeners for route changes in NextJS

```
  router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
  router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
```

you can reload the script when the route changes with the help of these events. you can fetch the script and append it at the end of the body script for every route change. so the memory of the adjs will be restarted

I hope this router.events helps, waiting for your feedback.

**UPDATE:**
According to your comment, I wanted to update here.
With the help of these router.events you have the control. You can manipulate the DOM. It should not be React specific solution or NextJS specific solution. You have the power of Javascript.

If you are the one adding all the ad divs, you can add an data attribute to select those divs later.

For example,
Lets say you have added this ad div

```
<div id="ad-tag-6098" ></div> // instead of this!
<div id="ad-tag-6098" data-ad="true" ></div> // add this one!
```

by using **routeChangeStart** event of **router.events**, you can select the divs with data-ad attribute and remove the filled content of them from DOM before **routeChangeComplete** event and when script is reloaded, it should not throw an error.

```
const adDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ad="true"]'); // you can get these divs and remove the child of them before routeChangeComplete cycle
```

What do you think about this updated part of my answer, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I was able to partially implement this solution. Using useEffect hooks, when the route changes, I am able to reload the script. However, the ad slots like <div id="ad-tag-6098" ></div> are already pre-filled with ads. And the script throws error that the ad is already filled. So, what needs to happen is that these ad slots also need to be removed and recreated for the ads to function well. Please see the last part of my question with the expected behaviour.

Comment: hi asanas, please take a look at my updated answer @asanas hope it helps

Comment: I believe this is workable. I'll still wait for more replies. Thanks for your effort in explaining.

Comment: Hi @asanas
If you do not want to manipulate the DOM via querySelectors. you can create an event bus and use it to publish changes. this is a minor example to show you a hint https://css-tricks.com/lets-create-a-lightweight-native-event-bus-in-javascript/ 

with this approach, you can subscribe to an event, like Refresh_Ads (the name is up to you) and in your ad component. and you can dispatch this event when routeChangeStart fired, clear ad div's filled content. so you do not have to use querySelector approach and you do not have to reload javascript

Answer (score 6):

Another simple trick would be to add unique query string which would cause the script to load and execute again and again.

For removing old `ads` [`Script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component `onLoad` event handler can be used.

```js
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home() {
  const unique_id = new Date().getTime();
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        id={unique_id}
        src={`//cdn.adsite.com/static/js/ad.js?v=${unique_id}`}
        onLoad={() => {
          // execute code after script load
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

---

---

Better approach would be to load script only once and refresh the slots which has been created with refresh functionality provided, or you can clear and load new ads with same functionality.

```js
function refreshAllSlots() {
   googletag.cmd.push(function() {
     googletag.pubads().refresh();
   });
}

function clearAllSlots() {
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.pubads().clear();
  });
}
```

**Note:**

- The example is for google ads but probably same can be achieved in other ads.
- These methods can be called using lifecycle methods or hooks or any other feasible method.

Comment: This ad script doesn't provide any such functions as refresh or clear. How can we do it with DOM in reactjs? If you could provide an example, it would be great. @chandan

Comment: @asanas can you share the ads script which you are using.

Comment: I shared the script in a chatroom with you. - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237719/room-for-asanas-and-chandan

Comment: @asanas you can check [here](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/adunit-refresh.html) for the refresh ads example.

Comment: I checked that. If you can create an example as a react component, it will be great. Otherwise, it's okay. I'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm inclined towards your idea of loading the script once, and then refreshing the ad slots on route change. But I'm not sure how to do a clean removal and reloading of the ad div while route change.

Comment: @asanas please share the page component where you have use the ads implementation

Comment: It's a simple component that renders the div <div id="ad-tag-6098" ></div>.